# rails 3 - form_for first parameter string with brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for, actionview

`ActionView::Base` instance method `form_for` can accept a string as its first argument. Sometimes you want to update multiple objects at once within an edit form. So you can pass a string as the first argument to `form_for` with a set of square brackets concatenated with the object name (e.g. `person[]`). Then you can iterate through the array of people objects and invoke the `FormBuilder` instance methods on it, such as `text_field`, passing the attribute associated with the person object. That's fine and understandable.

However, I was looking through the source and I come across this:

```
if @object_name.to_s.match(/\[\]$/)
  if object ||= @template.instance_variable_get("@#{Regexp.last_match.pre_match}") and object.respond_to?(:to_param)
    @auto_index = object.to_param
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "object[] naming but object param and @object var don't exist or don't respond to to_param: #{object.inspect}"
  end
end
```

`@object_name` is an argument passed into the constructor of `FormBuilder`, and it refers to that first parameter passed to `form_for`, such as `user[]`. Here we check if the string contains square brackets and if it does, we check the template `ActionView::Base` to see if it contains a `@user` instance variable (`Regexp.last_match.pre_match` returns `user` and then we just interpolate the `@` to build an instance variable). Remember that instance variables are copied from the controllers to view layer, so if we have it defined in the controller, it will be available in `ActionView`. So let's say that because we are in our edit form, we do have a `@user` object that exists. Here, we invoke the `to_param` method on it, which will return the `id` of the record as a string (assuming `to_param` has not been overwritten) and assign it to the `@auto_index` instance variable.

Here's my question. let's say that `@user` does exist and has an id of `1`, which is assigned to `@auto_index`. But if we are checking for a string with square brackets `user[]`, obviously we are expecting an array of `id`s, so why does it only check for one object and assign it to auto index, rather than grabbing the collection of user objects and assigning all their ids to auto index?

Please refer to line 1197:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb